# What can I do about 2x4 wood expansion joints that are above the surface of the concrete?

Tags: wood, concrete

I have a lot of concrete in my yard that has several 2x4 6-10 foot wood expansions.  The 2x4's are now between a 1/2" and a full inch above my concrete.  What can I do to fix this? I thought about a hammer and chisel, but it would take me a year!  Can I take the 2x4s out?  I've had this concrete for about 15 years.  No cracks anywhere just expanding wood!

Comment: You could take out the 2x4s but then you would have a crack to worry about. It may end up being a dirt filled weed magnet.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what you use this concrete pad for, you could take the plywood out and fill the gaps with polymeric sand. Once you water it in, the sand forms a locking pattern that resists weeds and is fairly easy to replace if it cracks.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try using a sledge hammer to hit a scrap piece of wood laid over the 2x4. This may work. If not, I would try prying the wood out with a crowbar, starting at an end, and using a piece of scrap wood for the fulcrum. If that worked, I'd rip off the 1/2" or 1" part that protrudes with a circular saw. If you can't pry it out, I'd use a reciprocating saw with a 12" blade and force the blade flush to the concrete to cut off the protruding wood.